# Ubuntu - Installing ScyllaDB - Missing optional package libsystemd (or libsystemd-daemon) - Wrong GCC version. Scylla needs GCC >= 7.3 to compile

Tags: apache, ubuntu, gcc, nosql, scylla

I try to install ScyllaDB in accordance to the [official documentation](https://www.scylladb.com/download/#source). I do it using:

```
git clone https://github.com/scylladb/scylla.git
cd scylla
git submodule update --init --recursive--init --recursive
sudo ./install-dependencies.sh
./configure.py --mode=release
ninja-build 
./build/release/scylla
```

however during `./configure.py --mode=release` I get:

```
Note: debug information disabled; upgrade your compiler
Missing optional package libsystemd (or alteratives libsystemd-daemon)
Wrong GCC version. Scylla needs GCC >= 7.3 to compile.
```

Any ideas how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you provide the output of cat /etc/*rel* ?

Comment: @ValerieParham-Thompson It's Ubuntu 14.04.5.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need to install GCC manually.

Apparently the install-dependencies.sh script does not install the correct packages.

Try installing GCC manually like this.

```
Install scylla-gcc73-c++
Install ragel-devel
Install scylla-boost163-devel
Install scylla-python34-pyparsing20
```

Then configure scylla like this:

```
python3.4 ./configure --mode=debug --compiler=/opt/scylladb/bin/g++-7.3 --python python3.4 --ldflag=-Wl,-rpath=/opt/scylladb/lib64 --cflags=-I/opt/scylladb/include
```

[Scilla Ticket: #3208 (Scylla fails to build)](https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/3208)

Answer (score 0):

If you are good with installing Scylla from packages, not compiling from source, you can do it from here: http://www.scylladb.com/download/
(require registration)